# Why root component isn't updated when the reducer state value changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to do authenticated route, and the problem is that my Root component isn't updated when the reducer value `loggedIn` is changed(fired in Login component). As a result, `authed` prop isn't updated also in `PrivateRoute`

Root:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
// import { BrowserRouter, Route, browserHistory, Switch } from "react-router";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import configureStore, {history} from '../store/configureStore'
import App from "./App";
import Startpage from "./startpage";
import PatientSearch from "./routes/patient/patientSearch";
import Technician from "./routes/technician/technician";
import Notes from "./routes/notes/notes";
import DeliveryReports from './routes/admin/deliveryReports/reports'
import Analytics from './routes/admin/analytics/analytics'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from "../actions";
import Login from './login';
import Cookies from "cookies-js";


const store = configureStore(/* provide initial state if any */)

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        authed === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props }
            }} />
    )} />
)

class Root extends Component {
  state = {loggedIn:false}


  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.isLoggedIn())
    console.log('hellOOOO')
    this.checkCookie()
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('rootprops', this.props.loggedIn, prevProps.loggedIn)
    this.props.loggedIn!==prevProps.loggedIn&&this.setState({loggedIn:this.props.loggedIn})
  }

  render() {
    console.log('propsroot', this.state.loggedIn)

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <Router >
            <App>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" authed={this.state.loggedIn} component={Startpage} />
                <Route
                    component={PatientSearch}
                    path="/patient/search"
                />

                <PrivateRoute
                    component={Technician}
                    path="/technician"
                    authed={this.state.loggedIn}
                />
                <Route
                    component={Login}
                    path="/login"
                />
                <Route
                    component={Analytics}
                    path="/analytics"
                />

                <Route
                    component={Notes}
                    path="/notes"
                />

                <Route
                    component={DeliveryReports}
                    path="/delivery_reports"
                />

              </Switch>
            </App>


          </Router>
        </ConnectedRouter>
       </Provider>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return {
    loggedIn: state.app.loggedIn,
    token: state.app.token,
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(hot(module)(Root))
```

ComponentDidUpdate isn't fired, even though the action is dispatched and the value of loggedIn is changed.

Reducer part :

```
case "SIGN_IN":
    return {
        ...state,
        loggedIn:true,
        errors:''}
```

EDIT: moved Routes to App component and everything works fine there. However, I get another problem: when I reload, or load web app for the first time, it redirects to `Login` component. The logs show that `loggedIn` is initially false, but then becomes true, but the component isn't rendered anyway(guess `authed` wasn't updated)

Comment: Using the redux state to update your components local state is an anti-pattern, instead consider just using the loggedIn prop from mapStateToProps throughout your component.

Comment: Why don't you connect PrivateRoute to redux and directly use the loggedIn?